# Generar borrador desde hoja de cálculo manteniendo formato

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, gmail

tengo una hoja de cálculo de google con varias pestañas. Una de ellas, llamada Carta A, se va rellenando sola con los datos que inserto en la Hoja 1.
La pestaña Carta A tiene formato de carta, con un membrete que incluye el logo de la empresa, una tabla y más texto a continuación de la carta.
Quiero hacer un script que me genere un borrador de correo utilizando la pestaña Carta A.
He conseguido que lo haga pero cambia el formato y pone todo el texto seguido y tampoco aparece el logo.

El script que tengo por ahora es este:

```
function emailStuff(e){

   var sheetName = "PEDIDOS A";  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

   if(sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn() == 11 && sheet.getRange(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow(), 2).getValue() != 0){   

     var sendMail = Browser.msgBox("QUIERES ENVIAR LA CARTA", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);    


    if(sendMail == "yes"){

          var email = sheet.getRange("F15").getValue();    
          var subject = sheet.getRange("I8:J8").getValues();

      var body = sheet.getRange("A1:K64").getValues();

      GmailApp.createDraft(
        email,            // Recipient
        subject, // Subject
        body, // Plaintext body


      );


    }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para genera un borrador de correo electrónico en Gmail con formato debes usar HTML y CSS. Considerando esto, para usar una hoja de cálculo de Google como plantilla del contenido del borrador, debes convertirla a HTML y CSS.

Para tu fortuna existe un proyecto de código abierto que te podría ser de utilidad

https://github.com/mogsdad/SheetConverter

Cabe destacar que luego de que se creó se han agregado más clases y métodos al [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) por lo que hay cosas de dicho proyecto que se pueden simplificar.