# ¿Cómo enviar un rango de Google Sheets por mail?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Hace tiempo vengo trabajando en un sistema de Hojas de Calculo compartidas que uso en mi trabajo para realizar pedidos de insumos. En esta ocasión, lo que necesitaría es crear una macro para que, al darle al botón "Registrar" se envíe todo el rango (B3:H100) a un correo electrónico especifico.

La verdad es que hasta ahora no encontré solución, he probado algunas cosas pero lo único que logro es que me envíe un mail con la palabra "[Range]" en donde se supone que debería ir el rango seleccionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Copiar el contenido del rango y pegarlo en el cuerpo del mensaje? ¿Crear un nuevo archivo, pegarle el rango y adjuntarlo? Podrías incluir en tu pregunta lo que has intentado hasta ahora (que no se trata de mostrar cosas que funcionen, acá traemos lo que no nos funciona :)  ). Recuerda que la opción para editar tu pregunta está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas

Answer (score 0):

Con Google Apps Script puedes enviar el cuerpo del mensaje de correo en texto plano o como HTML. Si deseas enviar el "rango" como se muestran en la interfaz de la hoja de cálculo de Google deberás crear la tabla y darle formato usando HTML.

Deberás leer los valores del rango usando `getValues` o `getDisplayValues`, seguramente este último te será más conveniente, para obtener los valores o los valores mostrados respectivamente. Además deberás usar los métodos correspondientes para obtener el tipo de línea, grosor y color de los bordes, el color de fondo, el tipo de fuente, el color de fuente, etc. Luego con estos datos deberás crear el HTML a ser enviado en el cuerpo del mensaje.

Relacionado

- [¿Es posible incluir un cuenta atrás en el cuerpo de un mensaje de correo eletrónico?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/255147/65)
- [Generar borrador desde hoja de cálculo manteniendo formato](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/298904/65)